# Windows Services open source framework

Tags: .net, open-source, windows-services

I was listening to a podcast a while back on an Open Source project.  I can't remember what the project was called, but the guys doing it said they'd split out their Windows Service support into a separate Open Source project.

Like I say, I can't remember the project or what they've called the break-out project.  All I remember is that it wraps Windows Services in .NET.

Anyone know what project this is?

Cheers

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you would need to "wrap" "windows services" in .net... 

.Net is fully capable of producing a windows service (and it's installer) rather easily.  What would you expect it to actually do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking of [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/).

Here's some information about it:

- [Creating a Windows Service with Topshelf](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/336)
- [Article at CodeBetter](http://codebetter.com/blogs/dru.sellers/archive/2009/01/11/topshelf.aspx)

Comment: That's exactly the one!  Thanks Erik.

Comment: Hey guys is there a more complete "how to" article to get top shelf up and running?

Comment: The TopShelf link above is not working, so here is the link to the project web site: http://topshelf-project.com/