# c# - how do i make application run as a service?

Tags: c#

i have a simple c# application that needs to run as service. how do i make it run as a service instead of just as an executable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [resources on creating a windows service using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688382/resources-on-creating-a-windows-service-using-c)

Comment: Here I have found step-by-step instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/593803/7713750

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Visual C# 2010 Recipies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225254) has an example in it which will show you exactly how to do this, which I've tried using VS 2008 and .NET 3.5.

It amounts to this:

1. Create a new "Windows Service" application in Visual Studio
2. Port your application's source into the service's execution model, AKA your Main function becomes part of an event handler triggered by a timer object or something along those lines
3. Add a Service Installer class to your Windows Service project - it'll look something like this code snippet below:

   ```
   [RunInstaller(true)]
   public partial class PollingServiceInstaller : Installer
   {
       public PollingServiceInstaller()
       {
           //Instantiate and configure a ServiceProcessInstaller
           ServiceProcessInstaller PollingService = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
           PollingService.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

           //Instantiate and configure a ServiceInstaller
           ServiceInstaller PollingInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
           PollingInstaller.DisplayName = "SMMD Polling Service Beta";
           PollingInstaller.ServiceName = "SMMD Polling Service Beta";
           PollingInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

           //Add both the service process installer and the service installer to the
           //Installers collection, which is inherited from the Installer base class.
           Installers.Add(PollingInstaller);
           Installers.Add(PollingService);
       }
   }
   ```

Finally you'll use a command line utility to actually install the service - you can read about how that works here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d8f300e3-6c09-424f-829e-c5fda34c1bc7

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tempate called "Windows Service" in visual studio. If you have any questions let me know, I write services all day long.

Comment: thanks so much jonathan i will definitely take you up on that

Answer (score 2):

There is the Open Source Framework that host .net application as Windows service. There are no pain installing, uninstalling windows service. It decouples very well. Please check this post [Topshelf Windows Service Framework Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013056/windows-services-open-source-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I want to show easly way to run service

At first you want if your service isn't stopped or something other status:

```
public static bool isServiceRunning(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

And next if service is not running you go to use this simple method

```
public static void runService(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        sc.Start();
    }
```